# Iteratively load image block by block where blocks are partially overlapped

Tags: python-3.x, gdal, rasterio

Trying to process a large satellite image (~10GB). For memory efficient processing chunk of image (`block`/`tile`) is being loaded into memory in each iteration.

[image: Tiled Image]

The sample code for this as below:

```
def process_image(src_img, dst_img, band_id=1):
    with rasterio.open(src_img) as src:
        kwargs = src.meta
        tiles = src.block_windows(band_id)
        with rasterio.open(dst_img, 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
            for idx, window in tiles:
                print("Processing Block: ", idx[0]+1, ", ", idx[1]+1)
                src_data = src.read(band_id, window=window)
                dst_data = src_data ** 2 # Do the Processing Here
                dst.write_band( band_id, dst_data, window=window)
    return 0
```

However, for any kind of processing which requires kernel wise operation (such as any `convolve` filter like `smoothing`) this leads to an issue in processing near the edges of the blocks. To address this, each block should be slightly overlapped as shown below:

[image: Overlapped Zoomed]

My objective is to load the blocks as the following where the amount of overlap can be adjusted according to the need.

[image: Overlapped Tile]

So far I did not find any straight forward way to achieve this. I would be grateful for any help in this regard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just expand your windows:

```
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio import windows

def overlapping_blocks(src, overlap=0, band=1):
    nols, nrows = src.meta['width'], src.meta['height']
    big_window = windows.Window(col_off=0, row_off=0, width=nols, height=nrows)
    for ji, window in src.block_windows(band):

        if overlap == 0:
            yield ji, window

        else:
            col_off = window.col_off - overlap
            row_off = window.row_off - overlap
            width = window.width + overlap * 2
            height = window.height + overlap * 2
            yield ji, windows.Window(col_off, row_off, width, height).intersection(big_window)
```

And you would use it like so:

```
def process_image(src_img, dst_img, band_id=1):
    with rasterio.open(src_img) as src:
        kwargs = src.meta
        with rasterio.open(dst_img, 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
            for idx, window in overlapping_block_windows(src, overlap=1, band=band_id):
                print("Processing Block: ", idx[0]+1, ", ", idx[1]+1)
                src_data = src.read(band_id, window=window)
                dst_data = src_data ** 2 # Do the Processing Here
                dst.write_band( band_id, dst_data, window=window)
    return 0
```

And here is a way to overlap both block windows and non-block windows, with an additional argument `boundless` to specify whether to extend windows beyond the raster extent, useful for [boundless reading](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.io.html?highlight=boundless#rasterio.io.BufferedDatasetWriter.read):

```
from itertools import product
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio import windows


def overlapping_windows(src, overlap, width, height, boundless=False):
    """"width & height not including overlap i.e requesting a 256x256 window with 
        1px overlap will return a 258x258 window (for non edge windows)"""
    offsets = product(range(0, src.meta['width'], width), range(0, src.meta['height'], height))
    big_window = windows.Window(col_off=0, row_off=0, width=src.meta['width'], height=src.meta['height'])
    for col_off, row_off in offsets:

        window = windows.Window(
            col_off=col_off - overlap,
            row_off=row_off - overlap,
            width=width + overlap * 2,
            height=height + overlap * 2)

        if boundless:
            yield window
        else:
            yield window.intersection(big_window)


def overlapping_blocks(src, overlap=0, band=1, boundless=False):

    big_window = windows.Window(col_off=0, row_off=0, width=src.meta['width'], height=src.meta['height'])
    for ji, window in src.block_windows(band):

        if overlap == 0:
            yield window

        else:
            window = windows.Window(
                col_off=window.col_off - overlap,
                row_off=window.row_off - overlap,
                width=window.width + overlap * 2,
                height=window.height + overlap * 2)
            if boundless:
                yield window
            else:
                yield window.intersection(big_window)
```

Output windows:
[image]

Comment: Since neither `GDAL` nor `rasterio` provides an convenient way to do it, this is the work around for now I guess. I started a [thread](https://rasterio.groups.io/g/main/message/143) in [rasterio main group](https://rasterio.groups.io/g/main) for discussion regarding implementing this feature into `rasterio`.

Comment: @tachyon - see bugfix edit. Original version was clipping off some pixels from right and lowr edges.