# windowed read and write of raster using rasterio

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

I am trying to read a raster with overlapping windows and doing some calculations on those windows. I am using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501232/iteratively-load-image-block-by-block-where-blocks-are-partially-overlapped/54525931#54525931). I want to do calucations on overlapping windows but want to write the windows without overlap.

```
from itertools import product
import rasterio 
from rasterio import windows


def overlapping_windows(src, overlap, width, height, boundless=False):
    """"width & height not including overlap i.e requesting a 256x256 window with 
        1px overlap will return a 258x258 window (for non edge windows)"""
    offsets = product(range(0, src.meta['width'], width), range(0, src.meta['height'], height))
    big_window = windows.Window(col_off=0, row_off=0, width=src.meta['width'], height=src.meta['height'])
    for col_off, row_off in offsets:

        window = windows.Window(
            col_off=col_off - overlap,
            row_off=row_off - overlap,
            width=width + overlap * 2,
            height=height + overlap * 2)

        if boundless:
            yield window, transform
        else:
            yield window.intersection(big_window), transform

def process_image(src_img, dst_img, band_id=1):
    with rasterio.open(src_img) as src:
        kwargs = src.meta
        with rasterio.open(dst_img, 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
            for window, transform in overlapping_windows(src, overlap, width, height, boundless=False):
                
                src_data = src.read(band_id, window=window)
                dst_data = src_data ** 2 # Do the Processing Here
                
               # write raster

               profile = {
               'driver': 'GTiff',
               'tiled': True,
               'compress': None
               }
              dtype = rasterio.dtypes.get_minimum_dtype(dst_data)
              crs = CRS.from_epsg(epsg)
              height = dst_data.shape[1]
              width = dst_data.shape[2]
              count = dst_data.shape[0]

              with rasterio.Env():
                  profile.update(
                  dtype=dtype,
                  count=count,
                  height=height,
                  width=width,
                  crs=crs,
                  transform=transform
                ) 
                with rasterio.open(out_path, 'w', **profile) as dst:
                    for band_idx in range(count):
                        arr_out = dst_data[band_idx, :, :, 0].astype(rasterio.dtypes.get_minimum_dtype(dst_data))
                        dst.write(arr_out, 1 + band_idx)
    return 0
```

This writes the overlapping windows, while I want to write non-overlapping windows but could not get my head around how to that.

Comment: Couldn't you set overlap = 0?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but since I had a similar problem:

you can define a window without overlap in the for loop like this:

```
 small_window = windows.Window(window.col_off+overlap, window.row_off+overlap, width, height)
 small_window = small_window.intersection(big_window)
```

You can then use this to write the tiled chunks without overlap:

```
dst.write(arr_out[overlap:-overlap, overlap:-overlap], 1+band_idx, window=small_window)
```